# How to override global list-item top-padding with a css code in wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, list

As the standard list-item padding in WordPress aligns list items a bit too close to each other, I am searching for a CSS code that addresses list items on a global level an sets a top-padding of 14px.

In other words I am searching for a way to globally apply the command `style="padding-top: 14px;"` 
via my css instead of pasting it into every list item like this:

```
<li style="padding-top: 14px;" >
```

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: You shouldn't need to do this normally, as your custom CSS should take precedence (make sure it appears after the theme's CSS), but have you tried `.list-item {padding-top: 14px !important;}`? Note that the `!important` rule should only be used as a last resort as it can't be overridden. Or change the `line-height` of the `.list-item` in your CSS.

Comment: I just tried .list-item {padding-top: 14px;} and it works very well. Thanks a lot, Matt!

Comment: No problem @AliceLeblanc, please mark the correct answer below : )

Answer (score 0):

Select the specific list item using the class in your CSS:

```
.list-item { padding-top: 14px; }
```